# How can I overlap an image with text, but both of them are inside the same anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to css and html, never touched JS or jquery.

I'm building as practice a website that looks like somewhat a portfolio site where I have some photos that are clickable. One thing that I wanted to do is, when a user hovers an image, an opaque box would pop up from the photo's bottom showing some text, the problem is that I want this text to be clickable as well so I put it inside the same anchor tag, but they don't overlap instead the clickable area stretches and the text gets positioned to the side of the image.

Is there a way of doing it so the "clickable area" doesn't stretch and the text overlap the image but without using the image as a background ?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve https://theme-frsch2.tumblr.com/ .

I've tried wrapping the text in a div and moving the text so it would overlap the image but the problem is that the "clickable" area would still be stretched anyway.

And this is what I got so far.

**HTML**

```css
#allimg{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

#allimg a{
 margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#allimg img{
 transition: 0.1s ease;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid pink;
}


#allimg img:hover{
 transform: scale(1.02);
}

#allimg a p{
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="allimg">
  <a href="link1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
    Text1
    </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
      Text2
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text3
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text4
      </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddel [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ryenra/z0ovpbe9/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to overlap text inside an image and achieve that hover effect on the [website](https://theme-frsch2.tumblr.com/) you attached

1. you have to use position: absolute for your text
2. and set the position for your anchor tag to relative
3. make it hideen by setting visibility property to hidden and opacity
   to 0
4. then on anchor tag hover, you set it back visible and 1 opacity

```css
#allimg{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

#allimg a{
 margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#allimg img{
 transition: 0.1s ease;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid pink;
}


#allimg img:hover{
 transform: scale(1.02);
}

#allimg a p{
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
#allimg a:hover p{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="allimg">
  <a href="link1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
    Text1
    </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
      Text2
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text3
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text4
      </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the image in parent container and text in child container, then in css file add 'position:relative' to the parent container and add 'position:absolute' to the child container.
This will overlap text and image.
Somewhat like this:
HTML Part:

```
<div class="parent">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="image">
 <div class="child">
 <p>Text goes here</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS Part:

```
.parent
{
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
  }
 .child
 {
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
  }
```

This will overlap text on image and you make changes as you want in the position of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution with smooth transition.

```css
#allimg{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

#allimg a{
  position: relative;
 margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#allimg img{
  position: abosolute;
  vertical-align: bottom;
 transition: 0.1s ease;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
 border: 1px solid pink;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


#allimg img:hover{
 transform: scale(1.02);
}

#allimg a p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5% 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#allimg a:hover{
 transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#allimg a:hover p{
 opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="allimg">
  <a href="link1">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
    Text1
    </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
      <p>
      Text2
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text3
      </p>
  </a>
  <a href="link4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
     <p>
      Text4
      </p>
  </a>
</div>
```